# Get id number from a value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the  following code :

```
 var currentuuid = $('#UUIDTOSEND').val();
        html1 = '';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "database/Emarps/websrvc/websrvc.php?task=getData&UUID=" + currentuuid + "&DataGt=stitrtmnt",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                client_history_list = $('#clinical_history_tbody').empty();

                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    html1 += '<tr>\n\
                        <td class = "form-group">\n\
            \n\
                        <input type = "text"   class = "form-control facility_name col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 "  readonly="" name="facility_name[]" id = "facility_name" value="' + data[i].facility_name + '" placeholder = "Facility Name">\n\
            </td>\n\
            <td class = "form-group">\n\
            \n\
            <input type = "text"  class = "form-control activity_timestamp col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 "  readonly="" name="activity_timestamp[]" id = "activity_timestamp" value="' + data[i].activity_timestamp + '" placeholder = "Visit Date">\n\
            </td>\n\\n\
 <td class = "form-group">\n\<input type = "text"  class = "form-control clinical_visit_id' + data[i].id + ' "  readonly="" name="clinical_visit_id[]" id = "clinical_visit_id" value="' + data[i].id + '" placeholder = "Visit ID">\n\
            \n\
            <button id="view_more' + data[i].id + '"  class="form-control view_more' + data[i].id + '" >Select/View More</button>\n\
            </td>\n\
            </tr>';
                    $("#clinical_history_tbody").on("click", ".view_more" + data[i].id, function () {

                        var clinic_visit_ids = $("#" + this.id.replace("view_more", "clinical_visit_id")).val();
                        alert(clinic_visit_ids);

                    });
                }
                $('#clinical_history_tbody').empty();
                $('#clinical_history_tbody').append(html1);
            }
        });
```

Which generates an auto table with data from the database. 
I want to get the  value of id from the  button when I click the Select/View More button, which runs the following the  `$("#clinical_history_tbody").on("click", ".view_more" + data[i].id, function () {` function on the  script. How can I get the  value of the  button id and replace it so that I can use it in the  clinic visit ? (When I alert I get an undefined).

Comment: use `$(this).attr('id')` this will give you the id of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` for "clinical_visit" is never assigned a numeric value at the end of its `id`.

```
<input type = "text"  class = "form-control clinical_visit_id' + data[i].id + ' "  readonly="" name="clinical_visit_id[]" id = "clinical_visit_id" value="' + data[i].id + '" placeholder = "Visit ID">
```

it is instead concatenated to its `class`.

this goes wrong when you are tring to fetch the "clinical visit" field, since you are looking for an `id` with value "clinical_visit_id[number]".
It isn't there, so you end up with an empty value :

```
var clinic_visit_ids = $("#" + this.id.replace("view_more", "clinical_visit_id")).val();
```

try this :

```
<input type = "text"  class = "form-control clinical_visit_id' + data[i].id + ' "  readonly="" name="clinical_visit_id[]" id = "clinical_visit_id'+data[i].id+'" value="' + data[i].id + '" placeholder = "Visit ID">
```

**OR**

look for the "clinical_visit" input by `class` instead of `id` (keep in mind you still need to sanitize your HTML, since two elements should never have the same `id`

That would look like this :

```
$("#clinical_history_tbody").on("click", ".view_more" + data[i].id, function () {
    var clinic_visit_ids = $("." + this.id.replace("view_more", "clinical_visit_id")).val();
    alert(clinic_visit_ids);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to get the id,

```
$("#clinical_history_tbody").on("click", "[class^=view_more]", function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

the above script wll bind click event to all the elements whose class name starts eith view_more. Then it will alert the current clicked elements id.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you change the id of the button:

```
$("#clinical_history_tbody").on("click",  function () {

    var clinic_visit_ids = $(this).attr('id', "clinical_visit_id");

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Attach event to that button onClick

```
 onClick=giveMeID(data[i].id)
```

in Html and then define in JS

```
function giveMeID(id){
//Do whatever you want
}
```

Here's Example [JSBIN DEMO](https://jsbin.com/wopamenula/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
<html>

<body>
    <button id="exa" onclick="genExamp()">Generate Example</button>
    <div id="ex"></div>
    <script>
        function genExamp(){
             var divEx = document.getElementById("ex");
                for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                        var childBtn='<button id="view_more'+i+'" onclick="giveMeID('+i+');">View/More'+i+'</button>';
                divEx.innerHTML+=childBtn;

                     }
        }
        //On Click:Gets ID and Replace it 
        function giveMeID(obj){
            var origID="view_more"+obj;
                var btn=document.getElementById('view_more'+obj);
            btn.id="view_more"+obj*10;
            var new_id=btn.id;
            alert("Original ID:"+origID+"\n"+"New ID:"+new_id);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```